# Magento 2.4.4 EE composer update issue

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, composer, magento2-enterprise, magento2.4.4

I have installed fresh Magento enterprise edition, after installation, the command

```
composer install
```

was run successfully. Now when I run the command

```
composer update
```

I am getting this error,

> Root composer.json requires magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.4,
> found magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.4.4] in the lock file but
> not in remote repositories, make sure you avoid updating this package
> to keep the one from the lock file.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: issue with auth.json may be ?

Comment: You are right, the auth.json file has credentials of non enterprise account, I have updated it with enterprise account and it's working.

Comment: Please add it in answer so that I can mark it correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong credential in auth.json.

Credentials should be used from enterprise account